# Updating Symfony 3.4 to Symfony 4.4 returns You have requested a non-existent parameter "secret". Did you mean this: "kernel.secret"?

Tags: php, symfony, environment-variables

I'm upgrading to Symfony 4.4 from from Symfony 3.4 and the parameters now use .env but terminal commands return the error message
In ParameterBag.php line 95:

```
    You have requested a non-existent parameter "secret". Did you mean this: "kernel.secret"?
```

the file config/packages/framework.yaml looks like this

```
 framework:
     secret: '%env(APP_SECRET)%'
```

I run  'composer dump-env dev' it returns the secret.

Any ideas why it's not found? what I need to resolve this? thanks

Comment: That's not a parameter but a configuration, parameters are (normally) configured in [`services.yaml`](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/configuration.html#configuration-parameters). You must be using `%secret%` or trying to retrieve the `secret` vía `ParameterBagInterface` in some other place.

Comment: You can confirm what @msg said by running `bin/console debug:container --parameter kernel.secret`. Your 3.4 app must have defined it's own secret parameter.  If you don't want to change any code then you can always just add your own secret parameter and set it to the value of kernel.secret.

Comment: @Cerad same error

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I had a '%secret' defined in security.yaml taken from version 3.4 so commented that out

```
    #remember_me:
    #secret:   '%secret%'
```